# What is the largest n for which one can solve within one second

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a suggested exercise from the Rosen Discrete Mathematics book. I am not looking for the answer ,  I already have the answer.  I am looking for someone to help explain the steps/means/procedures (what have you)it takes to get the answer.

The question is :

What is the largest n for which one can solve within one second a problem using an algorithm that requires f (n) bit operations, where each bit operation is carried out in 10^-9 seconds, with these functions f (n)?
Part C:

c. n*log(n)
I know the answer is :

f(n)<= 10^9

n*log(n)<=10^9

n<= 3.96x10^7
so n must be 3.96x10^7

The solution manual has given this answer, but it does not tell me how to get the answer. What must I do to get

n<= 3.96x10^7 from :

n*log(n) <= 10^9

Much thanks to anyone that helps me understand this

Comment: This seems much more of a math problem than a programming one.

Comment: My instructor said we could write a program to solve for n, I am just confused how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try it, but maybe I am wrong. So, from

n*log(n) <= 10^9

you get: n^n < 10^(10^9) (I hope I am not wrong). And here I think you need to try to find a number that elevated to himself is giving less than 10^(10^9). And by trying they find 3.96x10^9

Answer (score 0):

It's called "numerical mathematics". Most real world problems can't be solved by some rearranging of terms in a formula, but must be approximated. In this case: You want to solve

```
n ln (n) = 10^9 or n = 10^9 / ln (n).
```

Make a very rough guess n = 10^9.

Substitute n in the second formula: n = 10^9 / ln (n), gives n = 4.8255 x 10^7.

Substitute n again: n = 4.8255 x 10^7 / ln (4.8255 x 10^7) gives n = 5.6253 x 10^7.

Substitute n again: n = 5.6253 x 10^7 / ln (5.6253 x 10^7) gives n = 5.6022 x 10^7.

Substitute n again: n = 5.6022 x 10^7 / ln (5.6022 x 10^7) gives n = 5.6050 x 10^7.

Substitute n again: n = 5.6050 x 10^7 / ln (5.6050 x 10^7) gives n = 5.6048 x 10^7.

Substitute n again: n = 5.6048 x 10^7 / ln (5.6048 x 10^7) gives n = 5.6048 x 10^7.

Can't see where 3.96 x 10^7 would come from.